# Get stacktrace from Java (Apache Tomcat) backend on Flex frontend (connected by BlazeDS)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds

I'm using BlazeDS to connect my Flex front end to my Java backend, and was wondering if there is any way I can get the complete stack trace in case of an exception to be passed to the front end. When I set a break point in the exception handler in Flex, I just see a basic message, fault string etc.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I can think of (never tried): create a custom exception. Catch all serverside exceptions at highest level and rethrow your custom exception with the stacktrace of the original exception as a property. You should be able to access this clientside.

Comment: Ah that's smart, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: That worked! Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom exception; then catch all serverside exceptions at highest level and rethrow your custom exception with the stacktrace of the original exception as a property. You should be able to access this clientside.

Also, if you're using Spring on the server side, the [Spring BlazeDS integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) can translate server-side exceptions into cleaner client-side ones using [exception translators](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/index.html#exception-translators).