# faultString = "java.lang.NullPointerException : null"

Tags: apache-flex

i have been pulling my hair for days trying to figure out an error. I have a flex front-end with a locally installed tomcat and a java backend. When i click a button to do some action, i get this error message below

```
(mx.rpc::Fault)#0
  content = (null)
  errorID = 0
  faultCode = "Server.Processing"
  faultDetail = (null)
  faultString = "java.lang.NullPointerException : null"
  message = "faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'java.lang.NullPointerException : null' faultDetail:'null'"
  name = "Error"
  rootCause = (Object)#1
    cause = (null)
    localizedMessage = (null)
    message = (null)
    suppressed = (Array)#2
```

any tips on where to go from here? I have tried "google-ing" to no avail
Thanks

Comment: You should debug java on back-end

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik ...i know that. It was an intentional move on my part to display the message on the front-end. The issue is finding possible solutions to the error message and not where its displayed

Comment: The only possible 'solution' to the error message is that you have a nullpointer somewhere during the execution of your java code. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868131/get-stacktrace-from-java-apache-tomcat-backend-on-flex-frontend-connected-by/15077092#15077092) may help you get a better stacktrace on the client side, but as Timofei already pointed out, the easiest route is to simply debug the java code from within your IDE.

Comment: @RIAstar .. the issue was with my SessionFactory and hibernate syntax..hence the nPE...I got around the issue by using plain old spring-jdbc. Many Thanks though